# Closing DB connection in closeConnection() within finally block

Tags: java, try-finally

Below is my code snippet

```
public void closeConnection(){
    if(connection!=null){
    try {
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

I want to close the connection with in this method in `finally` block can any one please help...

My requirement is connection should be opened here...but `connection.close()` needs to be in the `finally` block ... something like this:

```
public void closeConnection() {
    if(connection!=null){
    try {}
    finally {
        connection.close();
    }       
}
```

Comment: Maybe you want to consider the new try-with-ressource in java 7? Example: http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-7-new-try-resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can do something like:-

public void closeConnection() {
    try{
    if(connection==null)
    {
    //Code to create connection and use DB operations
    }
}
    catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    finally{
            if(connection!=null){
              try {
                connection.close();
              } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
    }


        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do something like:

```
try {
  //do you db logic here.        
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: if I go ahead and do the above logic the connection will be close here...I dont want to close the connection here.My point is it fine to leave the try as blnk like this public void closeConnection(){
        if(connection!=null){
            try {}
finally{
                connection.close();`enter code here`
}

        }
    }

Comment: You will **have** to catch an `SQLException`, because connection.close() can sometimes throw it. There is no way to escape wrapping `connection.close` within `try`